# setting COOKIE_DOMAIN to share cookies not working

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, single-sign-on

I have Wordpress website on `www.something.com`, and another php script on sub-domain `www.panel.something.com`
my php script has its own separate database and user table
Im trying to implement **Single Sign On** from Wordress and remove registration and sign in process on my php script on sub domain
as I follow this answer here
[Single Sign On with SubDomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198853/single-sign-on-with-subdomains)

as a first step I tried to enable COOKIE on main domain and sub-domain
but when I put this in my `wp-config.php` it doesnt let me to sign in to Wordpress

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.something.com' );
```

even removing the dot

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'something.com' );
```

doesnt work

I even tried

```
define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'www.something.com' );
```

but it doesnt let me login in my main Wordpress site

Im trying to use the same cookie in my `www.something.com` as well as my sub-domain `www.panel.something.com`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that

`define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'yourdomain.com')`

must be placed in `wp-config.php` above this line:

`require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

which is at the bottom of the file usually.
(`wp-settings.php` defines `COOKIE_DOMAIN` too and PHP only allows you to define constants once)

You can check whether your config is being applied using chrome dev tools. View your site, in dev tools go to the `Application` tab, click `Cookies` and your domain on the left menu then find the cookie named `wordpress_logged_in_<COOKIEHASH>`. The `domain` column should match what you've set in `COOKIE_DOMAIN`.

If that cookie doesn't appear in the list you're not logged in to the current page.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone wondering in 2022 and possibly later, just changing the COOKIE_DOMAIN worked for me. I have been trying out multiple things and googling for some time now, but this is working fine now. So, just include this is your wp-config.php file:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'domain.com') // note there is no dot nor www.;
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

**Domain**
The (sub)domain that the cookie is available to. Setting this to a subdomain (such as 'www.example.com') will make the cookie available to that subdomain and all other sub-domains of it (i.e. w2.www.example.com). To make the cookie available to the whole domain (including all subdomains of it), simply set the value to the domain name ('example.com', in this case).

Older browsers still implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

Comment: This isn't working for me, with or without the leading `.`. Running WP v6.1. Tried it with both Firefox v111.0.1 and Chromium v111.0.5563.64. Any thoughts? My understanding is that I don't have to restart WP for the changes to take effect. But maybe there's a cache somewhere I'm missing?